# Maps points of intersection (Common Rectangle Area)

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, bing-maps, virtual-earth

Please help me how to find points of intersection between two rectangular areas...

For example:
I search the results for the viewable area in virtual earth maps v6.3

The map returned me the top left and bottom right points as latitude and longitude. Then i pan the area to move to different position. I have my old coordinates saved now i want to find the common area between the old viewable area and new viewable area. I already have points of top left and bottom right.

Comment: Can you please add a sketch of what you need?
Some two rectangles with 8 vertexes, with those you have and those you need.

Answer (score 0):

The Bing Maps v6.3 control is really old and shouldn't be used anymore. The Bing Maps v7 control replaced it about 4 years ago and is a much better map control all around.

As for question and finding points of intersections in v6.3 here are some related blog posts I wrote on this a long time ago:

http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/points-of-intersection-of-two-planes/
http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/point-of-intersection-of-two-polylines/